# How to set IntelliJ IDEA Project SDK

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-8, sdk, java-7

I just installed IntelliJ IDEA and when I try to create my first Project it asks for me to set up the Project SDK. When I click on "JDK" it asks for me to select the home directory of the JDK as shown in this image.

[image]

I'm having trouble locating where it is.

Comment: have you installed the jdk?

Answer (score 199, accepted):

For a new project select the home directory of the jdk

eg `C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_99`
or `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_99`

For an existing project.

1) You need to have a `jdk` installed on the system.

for instance in

`C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_99`

2) go to `project structure` under `File` menu  `ctrl+alt+shift+S`

3) `SDKs` is located under `Platform Settings`. Select it.

4) click the green `+` up the top of the window.

5) select `JDK` (I have to use keyboard to select it do not know why).

select the home directory for your jdk installation.

should be good to go.

Comment: Hey , so far i did all the required things and i still get ** Error:Invalid SDK Home path set. Please set your SDK path correctly. ** ..
Any further help ??

Comment: ultimate 2016.1 but never mind i fixed it :) thanks anyway

Comment: On Mac OSX find it with `$ echo $(/usr/libexec/java_home)` --gives me
`/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_20.jdk/Contents/Home`

Comment: I had to select JDK version in "Project" tab also (present in "Project Structure" dialog box) to run my project.

Comment: @HasS I had the same problem. My project used Maven so I just replaced any occurrence of 1.8 in pom.xml with 1.7 and that fixed it.

Answer (score 71):

For IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2 I did the following to fix this issue:
Go to your project structure
[image]
Now go to SDKs under platform settings and click the green add button.
Add your JDK path. In my case it was this path **C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144**
[image]
Now Just go Project under Project settings and select the project SDK.
[image]