# IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.3 giving error - Project SDK is not defined, even on setting Project SDK to Java 1.8 JDK

Tags: java, intellij-idea, sdk, java-8, macos-sierra

My Intellij IDEA 2017.1.3 on macOS Sierra is not picking up Java SDK path even on setting it up to 
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_102.jdk/Contents/Home

Am I missing something?

[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPAMb.png)

Comment: See this..
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16765726/how-to-set-intellij-idea-project-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16765726/how-to-set-intellij-idea-project-sdk)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set IntelliJ IDEA Project SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16765726/how-to-set-intellij-idea-project-sdk)

Comment: please see the comment of [How to set IntelliJ IDEA Project SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16765726/how-to-set-intellij-idea-project-sdk).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default path to the JDK folder should end up in the bin folder.

In windows this would be something like:
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin

And linux something like:
/usr/lib64/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0/jre/bin/java

Reinstalling the JDK would fix all issues anyhow. You can also check your java version (to see if it's properly installed) by typing either in cmd or terminal `java -version`