# how to add jdk9 to intellij IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-9

I've seen a couple of guides which show me to **NEW > module-info.java** I don't have that module-info.java item, I'm currently vert lost in that regard. I need someone to help me understand what I'm doing and what I'm supposed to do.

I've just installed IntelliJ, and am new to java (outside of android), I have no idea how to add jdk9 or even if *adding* is the right term.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/16765841/104891. The steps are the same except the JDK version you'll be using.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your question is poorly researched and you should put in more effort when asking on StackOverflow. Still, you're new, so here's a freeby:

- [download IntelliJ](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/), at least 2017.1.2, better 2017.2.1
- [download](http://jdk.java.net/9/) and install/unpack JDK 9
- [add it as SDK](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-sdks.html)  (software development kit) to IntelliJ
- [create a new project](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-a-java-module.html) and set JDK 9 as SDK
- make sure [project language level](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/project-page.html) is set to 9

Comment: Thanks. Coming from a Visual Studio background and trying to learn IntelliJ + Java this was a very helpful post for installing the newer JDKs.