# intellij idea does not see java 9 standard classes

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, shared-libraries, java-9

I've got a `maven` project that uses `Java 9`. It imported into `IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2.3 Community`.

But for some reason it cannot find standard java classes like `String` or `Float`. For example

[image]

When I try to `Setup Project JDK` it changes nothing

[image]

What is the problem?

`module-info` looks like this

```
module com.lapots.breed.platform.cloud.javacloudsample {
    requires spring.boot;
    requires hibernate.jpa;
    requires spring.web;
    requires spring.boot.autoconfigure;
}
```

Project itself is there [java-cloud-sample](https://github.com/lapots/java-cloud-sample)

Comment: Did you create a `module-info.java` with `requires java.base`?

Comment: Which JDK 9 build do you use?

Comment: @CrazyCoder 9+181

Comment: @nullpointer nope. added my `module-info` to question

Comment: @user1432980 and does adding `requires java.base` not solve your problem?

Comment: @nullpointer it marks it as red

Comment: @user1432980 What error does it read?

Comment: @nullpointer module not found `java.base`

Comment: @user1432980 Using your project itself. I am unable to reproduce the error. Probably check your IntelliJ configuration, specifically project structure for Project and SDK configuration. By the way intelliJ 2017.2.3 and jdk-9+181, here as well.

Comment: Looks like the SDK is not configured correctly in the IDE. You (mis-named) Classpath tab will is the modules in the JDK when you have it configured correctly.

Comment: @AlanBateman hm I though `9` is the new naming of `jdk` (instead of `1.9`). Indeed with `1.9`. Also it names it as `9` by default. it works now! Thanks.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46002269/6166627) help you?

Comment: @Sam, setting JDK was enough

Comment: @user1432980 I believe this should be closed.
This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

Comment: @lapots I am facing exact same problem on my mac. Could you please elaborate what solved your issue.

Comment: @Naman well I am not sure regarding latest versions of IDEA but I by default it configured java 9 as 9 version (new naming or something), I just changed to 1.9 (similar to 1.8)